# how to reset the NavigationView scroll position

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have navigationView as below,

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        style="@style/NavDrawer"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/list_navigation_menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/list_view_marigin_top"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="@dimen/list_view_divider_height"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/list_view_marigin_top"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

How can I have the NavigationView always start on its "original" scroll position whenever it's open, so the first menu item is always visible regardless of where the scroll position was left previously.

i tried below 3 lines/solution but it didnt work:

```
  ((NavigationMenuView)((NavigationView)mViewHolder.mNavigationView).getChildAt(0)).scrollToPosition(0);

    mViewHolder.mNavigationView.scrollTo(0,0);

    mViewHolder.mNavigationView.setVerticalScrollbarPosition(View.SCROLLBAR_POSITION_DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me
RecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(0);